# Create a custom command (not application) shortcut in Windows

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to create a custom command shortcut in windows to execute some basic actions, or modify the keys combinations of existing ones?

I suppose to have a greater flexibility I could just create some batch or perl (or whatever) scripts and just create application shortcuts for those, but I was wondering if Windows offer the flexibility to add custom command shortcuts, maybe via the registry?

For example win 7 introduces the ALT+SHIFT+N shortcut to create a new folder, which is simply great. But before there was no shortcut for this kind of basic operation, and it's something that somebody may like to implement if missing.

Comment: You will have to write a program.

Comment: Create a batch file that does the action that you want in some folder somewhere. Now create a shortcut to that batch file (the shortcut living on your desktop). Right click the shortcut, go to properties and assign a hotkeys combination. When you type the combination, the shortcut will "run", launching your batch program to do whatever action you please.

Comment: @SecurityMatt that's exactly what I came up with, but some things just aren't so easy to implement, for example how could I create a script to convert all filenames in current folder to lowercase? I would have to copy first the script to this folder right? That's not something desirable.

Answer (score 12):

This is not exactly what you want.

- But I think this might be helpful [Hot Key Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775233(v=vs.85).aspx) (Developer's Choice)
- If you just need custom Keyboard shortcuts for Triggering an action try [Auto Hot Key](http://www.autohotkey.com/).
  (End Users' Choice)

I prefer using Auto Hot Key,

- It is open-source utility for Windows.
- It offers many features besides application launching,
- you can make any key or mouse button act as a modifier key.
- You can even OVERRIDE Windows' own shortcut keys such as Win+E and Win+R.
- You can also automate a lot of other actions using it.

Answer (score 0):

Tasklayout always helps me to open my favorite folders and applications with hotkeys. I have created additional layouts to lock current Windows session, to hibernate my workstation, etc. 
The point is: Tasklayout allow user to specify actual command line that should be executed when layout is restored. Thus, you can configure Tasklayout to run any commands with a shortcut.